# Setup SQL server and web server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008

I've always used the database server and the web server on the same machine. Now I have two machines one database one web server. What do I need to do on the software side and hardware side?

Answer (score 1):

On the software side, you need to change the configurations of the web application to connect to the new database server.

From hardware perspective you need not change much. In SQL Server if you have set max memory, that needs to modified so that it can make use of the memory available in the new server.

Answer (score 1):

On the hardware side, there's nothing which needs to be done other than machine sure that the web server can contact the database server over the network.

On the web server change the connection string to use the remote server name.

On the database server make sure that the database instance is setup to accept remote connections and that the memory settings are configured to use most of the memory (leaving about 1-2 gigs for the OS).

Like normal make sure that everything is fully patched and firewalled, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Without a lot of information there isn't much to say....

When you say software, what software do you mean, the OS, IIS, Database server or your application?

On the hardware side, do you already have the hardware (you say you have two machines)? I guess you need to be more specific with your questions and provide more information.